# One Vs. Mutiple DbContext in one project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity, dbcontext

I am building a MVC 4 with Data Entity web app. The app need to connect two database that are in the same db server. I need to use the data from database 1 to search the data on the database 2. For a good practice and performance, should I have two DbContext or one?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need two separate connection strings and connections, so use two different contexts and query one based on the results from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless the DB schema structures  are the same. Trying to access 2 different databases with the same context will cause you more problems than it solves.  And as Konstantin points Out 2 connection strings will be necessary.
Use the normal Create model/context from DB process twice.

Answer (score 0):

For this case I prefer this way :

you create your context from the DB you need to write in (let's say DB1). An then I create view (in DB1) referencing the tables in the other DB (DB2). And this add a security level : I'll never insert anything in the DB2 (because views are readonly with entity framework).